# Wiring Java not always works

Tags: raspbian, java, wiringpi

I just started my developments with wiring pi but i'm facing some problems with method not always being executed on Raspberry.

```
    // LED1
    SoftPwm.softPwmCreate(0, 0, 100); // RED
    SoftPwm.softPwmCreate(1, 0, 100); // GREEN
    SoftPwm.softPwmCreate(2, 0, 100); // BLUE

    // LED2
    SoftPwm.softPwmCreate(3, 0, 100); // RED
    SoftPwm.softPwmCreate(4, 0, 100); // GREEN
    SoftPwm.softPwmCreate(5, 0, 100); // BLUE

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(0, 0);
        SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(1, 100);
        SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(2, 0);
        SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(3, 0);
        SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(4, 100);
        SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(5, 0);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(0, 0);
        SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(1, 0);
        SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(2, 0);
        SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(3, 0);
        SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(4, 0);
        SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(5, 0);
        Thread.sleep(2000); //THIS WAS MISSING
    }

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(0, 100);
    SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(1, 0);
    SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(2, 0);
    SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(3, 100);
    SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(4, 0);
    SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(5, 0);

    Thread.sleep(2000);

    SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(0, 0);
    SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(1, 0);
    SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(2, 0);
    SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(3, 0);
    SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(4, 0);
    SoftPwm.softPwmWrite(5, 0);
```

This is nothing complex but in the for loop the led never turns off, and sometimes the last piece ( turn off the leds) doesn't happen.

Do you have any idea why?
I have an Pl9823-F8 led

Comment: *"sometimes the last piece ( turn off the leds) doesn't happen."* -> Please add a photograph or diagram of exactly how you have the LEDs wired up.

Comment: The question was answered, thanks for you help! i was missing one sleep, see the edit on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in the for loop the led never turns off

Here's a loop much like that one.

```
boolean x;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    x = true;
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    x = false;
}
```

This loop will take about 20 seconds to complete.  Looking closely, for how many of those seconds will `x` be `true`?

About 20.

Doing some simple math, for how many seconds will `x` be `false`? *About 0.*

In case it isn't obvious yet, what you're doing is turning the LEDs on, sleeping for 2 seconds, then turning them off, then immediately turning them on again.  Since PWM by nature is actually a rapid on/off pulse, this will have little or no impact; the LEDs will effectively *always* be in the state described in the first half of the loop.

Comment: While i was reading this i thought: he must me joking , am i really that dumb? Of course, sorry about this stupid and 2 year old question

Comment: I've done things equally daft and stared at them for half the afternoon before realizing I should quit programming and stay away from computers ;)